# Another way of saying that things have gone bad

Tags: idiom-request

What are some of the idioms you guys use to say that things were good for a period of time, and then they started going bad?

There are few idioms I know, but I would like to learn new ones. Here they are:

1. **To go south**

> Things really started **going south** after he quit his job.

2. **To go bad**

> Everything  **went** really **bad** at the company after his passing.

3. **To go downhill**

> Our relationship **went** completely **downhill** after I found out that he was cheating on me.

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Exchange is designed to attract *definitive* answers; requests for open-ended lists of suggestions are not well-suited to the format, because there is no one "right" answer. You already know several common expressions; have you tried entering them into a thesaurus?

Comment: Not yet. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2):

> Things went to pot.

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-to-pot)

Interestingly, this originates from when food was scarce, people would leave the bones, fat and undesirable portions behind after eating their meal. These second-rate items would be used for soup the next day, so as such, the poor-quality leftovers would "go to pot".

> Things went to sh*t.

Obviously the latter being slightly ruder!

South and Downhill are also both suitable alternatives.

Comment: Also, things went *pear-shaped.*

Comment: OOO I like it! Good thought.